# fs.writeFile with 'wx' flag does not fail if file exists

Tags: node.js, fs

I'm using `FileCookieStore` which requires a path to a cookiefile and that this file is already created. I want to use `fs.writeFile` to create this file if it does not already exist, but not to overwrite it if it *does* exist. However, in the implementation below, it overwrites the content of the cookiefile even if it exists, even though the `wx` -flag should throw an error and not overwrite the file if it already exists.

```
var cookiePath = "cookie.json"

fs.writeFile(cookiePath, null, { flags: 'wx' }, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});

var j = request.jar(new FileCookieStore(cookiePath));
request = request.defaults({ jar : j });

function login(callback) {
    // puts data into j which automatically writes the content to cookiePath
}
```

Have I misunderstood the proper use of `writeFile` with the `wx`-flag? If I run `login()` the content of the cookie is automatically saved to cookie.json, but if I run the file again without calling `login`, `fs.writeFile` empties the cookiefile.

Answer (score 4):

your code should be:

fs.writeFile(cookiePath, null, { **flag**: 'wx' }, function (err)

:)

Comment: indeed it is just `flag`

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of writeFile method as per documentation is `fs.writeFile(file, data[, options], callback)`

.

I can see that you are sending null in place of data to be written. That could be the reason behind your empty cookie file.